# Unity3D smooth camera movement and lookAt

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, camera

Got stuck with camera movement in my Unity3D C# project.

What I have:

- some objects on the scene
- a camera, which would fly from any object's poition or from it's own current position

What I need:

- smooth rotare camera to one of the object's origin
- fly to the spot near the object (there is an **empty**, so I fly to empty's coords)

**Algorithm**: rotate to the object's origin, when rotation finishes, start to fly to the empty's position. while flying, look at object's origin.

The problem is that it's not smooth, the camera "jumps" at the end of the movement.

My C# code (attached to the camera):

```cs
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;

public class testMove : MonoBehaviour {
    public GameObject startObj;
    public GameObject endObj;    
    public float speed = 1.0F;
    private float startTime;
    private float journeyLength;
    private string endObjName;
    private GameObject endObjLookAt;
    void Start () {
        startTime = Time.time;        
        if (startObj) {            
        } else {
            startObj = this.gameObject;
        }       
        journeyLength = Vector3.Distance(startObj.transform.position, endObj.transform.position);        
        endObjName = endObj.name;
        endObjLookAt = GameObject.Find(endObjName + "LookAt");
    }   

    void Update () {
        if (endObj) {            
            float distCovered = (Time.time - startTime) * speed;
            float fracJourney = distCovered / journeyLength;
            tweenLook(endObjLookAt, fracJourney);
            float angle = Quaternion.Angle(transform.rotation, Quaternion.LookRotation(endObjLookAt.transform.position - transform.position));            
            if (angle <= 0.0001) { 
                Debug.Log("rotation finished");
                tweenPos(startObj, endObj, fracJourney);
                transform.LookAt(endObjLookAt.transform.position);                
            }
        }
    }

    private void tweenPos(GameObject startObj, GameObject endObj, float fracJourney) {
        Vector3 newposition = Vector3.Lerp(startObj.transform.position, endObj.transform.position, fracJourney);        
        transform.position = newposition;        
    }

    private void tweenLook(GameObject endObjLookAt, float fracJourney) {
        Quaternion newrotation = Quaternion.LookRotation(endObjLookAt.transform.position - transform.position);
        transform.rotation = Quaternion.Slerp(transform.rotation, newrotation, fracJourney);
    }
}
```

Comment: why not `Lerp()`ing?

Comment: @YotamSalmon Could you be polite to tell me what parameter should i Lerp and where? Sorry, i'm very new to Unity. Just trying to port my ThreeJs camera movement in Unity.

Comment: Sorry if I seemed rude, that was never the intention :) You pass a T initial (can be int, float, vector, Quaterion, etc), T final, and lerping factor (0-1), and it actually lerps the movement. Usually you use Time.deltaTime * N (N varies) as the lerping factor

Comment: @YotamSalmon That's ok, I didn't think you a rude! Thank you! :)

Comment: @ИванДобряков: in your comment earlier, I think you meant "Could you be kind enough to tell me", which is a very polite way of asking for something. In British/American English we would generally say "Could you tell me" as it is more straightforward. Hope that helps `:-)`.

Comment: @halfer Many thanks to yoo, got it!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since what you're trying to achieve implies doing actions one after another, I'd recommend using a **Coroutine**:

```
public class testMove : MonoBehaviour
{
    public Transform startObj;
    public Transform endObj;
    private Transform endObjLookAt;

    public float rotationDuration;
    public AnimationCurve rotationCurve;

    public float movementDuration;
    public AnimationCurve movementCurve;

    private IEnumerator moveAndRotateCameraIEnumerator;

    void Start()
    {
        // If you want to do it on start just call MoveAndRotateCamera() here, else call if from anywhere you want (a script, a game button, ...)
    }

    void Update()
    {
        if(Input.GetKeyDown(KeyCode.Space))
        {
            MoveAndRotateCamera();
        }
    }

    public void MoveAndRotateCamera(Transform startTransform = null, Transform endTransform = null)
    {
        if(startTransform)
        {
            startObj = startTransform;
        }
        else
        {
            startObj = this.transform;
        }

        if(endTransform)
        {
            endObj = endTransform;
        }
        endObjLookAt = GameObject.Find(endObj.name + "LookAt").transform;

        if(moveAndRotateCameraIEnumerator != null)
        {
            StopCoroutine(moveAndRotateCameraIEnumerator);
        }
        moveAndRotateCameraIEnumerator = MoveAndRotateCameraCoroutine();
        StartCoroutine(moveAndRotateCameraIEnumerator);
    }

    private IEnumerator MoveAndRotateCameraCoroutine()
    {
        //ROTATION
        Vector3 startEulerAngles = transform.eulerAngles;
        transform.LookAt(endObjLookAt);
        Vector3 deltaEulerAngles = new Vector3(Mathf.DeltaAngle(startEulerAngles.x, transform.eulerAngles.x), Mathf.DeltaAngle(startEulerAngles.y, transform.eulerAngles.y), Mathf.DeltaAngle(startEulerAngles.z, transform.eulerAngles.z));

        Debug.Log("Starting rotation...");
        float timer = 0.0f;
        while(timer < rotationDuration)
        {
            timer += Time.deltaTime;
            transform.eulerAngles = startEulerAngles + deltaEulerAngles * rotationCurve.Evaluate(timer / rotationDuration);
            yield return new WaitForEndOfFrame();
        }
        transform.eulerAngles = startEulerAngles + deltaEulerAngles;
        Debug.Log("Rotation done!");
        //----

        //MOVEMENT
        Vector3 startPosition = transform.position;

        Debug.Log("Starting movement...");
        timer = 0.0f;
        while(timer < movementDuration)
        {
            timer += Time.deltaTime;
            transform.position = Vector3.Lerp(startPosition, endObj.position, movementCurve.Evaluate(timer / movementDuration));
            transform.LookAt(endObjLookAt);
            yield return new WaitForEndOfFrame();
        }
        transform.position = endObj.position;
        transform.LookAt(endObjLookAt);
        Debug.Log("Movement done!");
        //----
    }
}
```

Please note a few things here:

- Changed your **GameObject** variables to **Transform** ones because you always used them to get to the **Transform** component so you can use it directly instead
- Added a time notion instead of a speed notion for rotation and movement (you can also use speed instead: simply multiply the `Time.deltaTime` by your speed factor)
- Using **AnimationCurve** allows you to adjust the way the rotation/movement will occur: simply set the curve in Inspector (curve must start at (0, 0) and end at (1, 1))

*Hope this helps,*

Comment: Many-many thanks to you! Wanna get you some beer (: But still got one trouble: camera makes a jump at last frame. Try to explain, what i mean: Think, we have 30 frames of this movement. On 29th, we have camera looking at our object, but it is not parallel to the object orientation (feels like you looking at something with an angle), but on the 30th frame, it looks normal way. Hope you could understand my poor description

Comment: Are you sure the **AnimationCurve** curve ends at (1.0, 1.0) on the inspector (I just tried to run it multiple times and didn't have any issue)? Hint: you can use Ctrl key to snap your curve points to round values.

Comment: Yes, i'm sure, i've selected my curves from standart presets. I'll try to figure out what's wrong. Many thanks to you!

Comment: I guess I figured what's the problem (**Transform** eulerAngles having a non 0 value so `LookAt()` changes the orientation) : I'll edit my answer a bit later :)

Comment: Thank you so much!

Comment: Just figured out what was wrong. My Empty (an object, the camera fly to) is straight up the other empty (look at). I moved the first empty and got everything ok! My fault, your code is pretty awesome! Have a nice day!